Supermicro M12SWA-TF microphone input
I have a workstation with a Supermicro M12SWA-TF motherboard.
I'm trying to get microphone input to work on it, but it doesn't seem to work. The audio device built into the motherboard gets recognized as a generic USB audio:
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 15d9:1c1c Trust International B.V. USB Audio
The motherboard has normal speaker out jack (which works), and also  line out, line in, microphone and SPIDF. In the PulseAudio Volume control, I can set different profiles, but with all of them only the green speaker out jack provides any output, and there is no reaction to any sound on the microphone (either in Audacity or Volume Control monitoring)
I've tried to use hdajackretask to configure the audio jacks, but this audio card doesn't appear on the list.
I'm running:
LSB Version:    core-11.1.0ubuntu4-noarch:security-11.1.0ubuntu4-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
Linux 6.5.0-21-generic #21~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Feb  9 13:32:52 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
Does anyone have any ideas why only the speaker out works?

Maybe the generic USB Audio driver cannot assign functionality to the jacks? But I have no idea how to reassign them.
